# In C++, what is the difference between LONG and long? (Uppercase and lowercase difference)

Tags: c++, types

C++ in Visual Visual Studio, "LONG" shown green, while "long" shown blue.

Is there any difference using one? Any disadvantages of using one?
The colors mean something?

I am just curious about it and found nothing really explaining this.

Comment: `long` is C++ type, `LONG` is not a type, it's a macro defined somewhere in the Windows SDK. Macros and types are colored differently.

Comment: @273K No, `LONG` is not a macro. There is a `typedef long LONG;` inside `winnt.h`. On Visual Studio, keywords are blue, and identifiers are cyan.

Comment: There are almost no uppercase names defined by the C++ standard. If you see an uppercase name it is most likely something that someone has invented. In this case it was invented by Microsoft as part of their Windows API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`long` is part of the C++ languge standard. `LONG` is a definition in a header that you included (probably resolving to `long`). To see the definition of `LONG`, try <kbd>Ctrl+Left Mouse button</kbd>, which works in most IDEs. The different colors are defined in your IDE depending on the type of symbol (e.g. Preprocessor constant, typedef, class, string, function, ...).